# Google CSE: how to eliminate css google?

Tags: javascript, html, google-custom-search

I explain my problem:

I would like to create a search engine on my website through the service "Google custom search engine"
the problem is that I do not like the search bar and I find it quite boring work on the whole css created by google.
it is possible delete its css?

But the css to the results page is fine ...

This is the generated code:

```
<script>
  (function() {
var cx = '015736343358803935205:m2shzyx2lrg';
var gcse = document.createElement('script');
gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
 })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: Just answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735333/custom-google-custom-search-gcs-text-and-styling/33847251#33847251

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be very useful perhaps?

Example for the search controls:

```
<SearchControls input_border_color="#BCCDF0"
                button_border_color="#666666"
                button_background_color="#CECECE"
                tab_border_color="#E9E9E9"
                tab_background_color="#E9E9E9"
                tab_selected_border_color="#FF9900"
                tab_selected_background_color="#FFFFFF" />
```

[Look and Feel | Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/ui_xml?hl=en)

**Update:**

> To customize the search box:
>    1.On the Control Panel, on the left-hand menu, click Look and feel.
>
> 2.In the Customize a style section, click the options you want.
>
> 3.Click Customize, and then: 
>   •To change the border and background of the whole custom search element, click the >Global Styles tab. 
>   •To
>   change the background color of the Search button and search input box,
>   click Search Controls
>
> •Click Save & Get Code.

Adapted from [Instructions for customized UI for Search](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1726884?hl=en)

Comment: Sorry i dont understand... Where i can put that code??? So.. my problem is that i don't like all html code created for search bar..... And i want to delete it

Comment: Maybe this will help now. This will then generate the design you want. https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1726884?hl=en

Comment: Thanks but it does not solve anything that way ...
I wish google cse worked with "my" search bar. Is there a way to avoid it being created all the html structure of the search bar and all its CSS?

Comment: I'm afraid not if all these do not work. Because google requires their own js to run on. Sorry.